# NodeJS request reset session

Tags: node.js, request, express-session

I am doing a post request from my server to another server and for it i'm using the library https://github.com/request/request.

So, I use the next code:

```
router.post('/extern/*', function(req, res, next) {
    var path = req.params['0'];
    var input = req.body.text;
    var encript = crypto.encrypt(input);

    request.post(config.petitionServer + path).form({data: encript}).pipe(res)
});
```

The session has been initialized before calling this post, but when it executes, the session is reseted. So, in this case, I lose the csrf code from the session var.

The error is in the 'pipe' function, because if I call it I lose the session, not in other case, but I need to use it.

How can I use the pipe function without lose the actual session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution and it was my bad.

Session is in `req.session` and the petition server was using also the express-session module. When request was received by petition server, this one replaced the session var by the one of the petition server.

The solution was to remove express-session module from petition server.

Anothe solution could be manage the session from the host server preventing to replace it. But I didnt do it

Answer (score 1):

I believe express-session is saving it's sessions into cookies and what you are doing is piping the hole response from `config.petitionServer + path` to client so it overwrites cookies that the express-session has saved. Maybe it would be a better idea just to pipe the body of the respone?

```
router.post('/extern/*', function(req, res, next) {
var path = req.params['0'];
var input = req.body.text;
var encript = crypto.encrypt(input);

request.post({url: config.petitionServer + path, formData: {data: encript}, function(err, httpResponse, body))
    res.send(body);
});
```

Comment: I tryed it and it works in text responses but its not fine with responses which has files. Maybe the code should be more complex. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, your express session is getting reset by the cookie that is sent from the other server.

There's a couple of ways you could solve this problem. If you don't need the cookie from your petition server, you could delete the header before you pipe the response:

```
router.post('/myServerUrl', function(req, res) {
  request.post('/remoteServerUrl', { data })
    .on('response', function(response) {
      delete response.headers['set-cookie'];
    })
    .pipe(res);
});
```

If you don't want to modify any headers, you should be able to pipe the response inside of the response handler along with the content type.

```
router.post('/myServerUrl', function(req, res) {
  request.post('/remoteServerUrl', { data })
    .on('response', function(response) {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
      response.pipe(res);
    });
});
```